# Long range communication module with high data rate (e.g. for video streaming)?

Tags: linux, wifi, wireless, raspberry-pi, remote-control

I am building a quadcopter and I am searching for a communication module for the **raspberry pi**, which can send big data over long range.

**I need a module with a range of approximately 1 - 2 km range, a daterate of 1,500 - 4,000 KB / second (for video streaming) and [RSSI](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Signal_Strength_Indication) support.**

I know that this is possible, because the [DJI Marvic Pro 2](https://www.dji.com/de/mavic-2/info) drone is able to create a video stream in Full HD (1920 x 180 pixels) up to 8 km.

**In the best case:**
The module creates a livestream of 1280 x 720 pixels.

**Realistic:** 480 x 852 pixels (in case of need, less) are also ok.

I think the best frequency is between **1.2Ghz and 5.8Ghz** (This is also a license-free ISM band)

Here are some that I have looked at, but **do not** meet my requirements:

**SI4432**

- RSSI: yes
- range: 1.5km
- rate: **256KB / s**

**RFM95 oder RFM98**

- range 2.5km
- RSSI: yes
- **rate: 300KB / s**

**SX1276**

- range 5 km
- RSSI: yes
- **rate: 5KB / s**

**HC-12**

- range: 1.8km
- **RSSI: no**
- rate: 5000 KB / s

Thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: DJI streams video as analog signal. And it does not stream it as HD (it records it in HD). Any LRS uses analog signal. There are few systems for HD video downlink but it costs a lot. Use any 5.8 Ghz 800mW and you will get what you need. Record video onboard.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for the helpful information. I have done a lot of research and discovered that in the country where I live (Austria), in 5.8GHz only up to 25mW are allowed. How far is the signal with 25mW?

Comment: Depends on anthenas, enveronment and other things. But not too far. Take a look on 1.2 or 2.4 GHz. Any way, for long range you should stay with something 200mW and more.

Comment: By thew way, you can try [this one](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/blacksheep-TBS-Unify-PRO-RACE-5G8-5-8-hv-Race-V2-5-8/32842948655.html). It has changable power from 25mW to 200mW (HV and V2 versions up to 800mW) so it feets your country limitations but you can switch it to high power when needed. If you use Spektrum TX and RX you can do it over the air on the fly.

Comment: Just price info (thi is not the best one): https://www.flyingtech.co.uk/fpv-camera-gimbals/r2teck-dvl1-1080p-full-hd-fpv-digital-video-downlink-system

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks a lot. The transmitter looks very good. For your price info: Are you sure that there is no cheap good video system?
What about [this one](https://www.amazon.com/TENINYU-Wireless-Transmitter-Receiver-Multicopter/dp/B01LZ8ZVG5/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1535279499&sr=8-2&keywords=fpv+video+transmission+system)?
I actually set my price limit to about 100 - 150 €. Do you think there is something good here? If necessary, only 30fps and 1km range.   :/

Comment: No cheap solution for HD. RC832 and TS832 are very good. I use them on my hexacopter for video downlink. Its not HD but good enough (it is transmitted from GoPro, so I have HD video recorded). But for TX I do recommend to use TBS. It lighter and smaller than RC832 with the same output power. And you should not use standard anthena.something like [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/5-8-GHz-FPV-Straight-Shape-L-Type-Inner-Needle-inner-Hole-Cloverleaf-5-8Ghz-Antennas/32801585451.html)

Comment: Also note that x832 requires at least 12V power supply (3S LiPo).

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thank you for your advice, I searched the internet again. I also use a GoPro [Hero3]. Can you please check if all parts fit together? My parts: [Transmitter](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/blacksheep-TBS-Unify-PRO-RACE-5G8-5-8-hv-Race-V2-5-8/32842948655.html) [Receiver](https://www.amazon.de/Kanal-Video-Empf%C3%A4nger-RC832-RACEBAND/dp/B071XHTDH3/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1535293005&sr=8-2&keywords=RC832) [Camera Mount](https://www.amazon.de/video-output-power-cable-camera/dp/B07FKP7X47/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1535293902&sr=8-7&keywords=GoPro+Fpv)

Comment: And how did you do that with the GoPro? Does it work automatically when you attach the GoPro, or do you need to install something else?

Comment: Yes, good TX/RX (just try to look on aliexpress for same RX, it can be found with less price there). I use Hero 4 with identical cable. GoPro has AV output through USB so you simple connect it with that cable to you VTX and get video on the groud. I do not use power for GoPro through USB, only internall battery. You have to start recording manually on your GoPro camera. Video transmitted always when GoPro is turned ON.

Comment: Thanks, I unfortunately did not find a transmitter from the same kind. Can you please take a look? And you are sure that the receiver has to be 800mW, because that's the race version as I understood and the race version has only 200mW.

Comment: [RC832 - $13](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/FPV-RC832-5-8G-48CH-600mw-Aerial-Photography-5-8GHz-AV-Receiver-System-With-A-V/32776272906.html). Yes, TX is 200 mW.

Comment: [RC8232Plus - $13](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Emax-MT2204-2204-2300KV-Brushless-motor-for-QAV250-robocat-270-Quadcopter-multicopter/32578444207.html)

Comment: Is it also possible to switch to 25mW that is legal in Austria?

Comment: RX doe snot have any "power" because it "sends" nothing, just receive. Only anthena is important for the receiver (RX). TX "sends" something so it has output power. By the link you (and I) gave you can find a table that shows that the TX (transmitter) has ajustable (switchable) output power from 25 mW to 200mW (for Race edition). One of the TX images shows the instruction that says that you can change output power by pressing button (you also can chang eit by your Radio TX if use Spektrum). So the answer is yes, you can change the TX output power to 25mW.

Comment: Thank you. That mean, the BlackSheep TBS Unify Pro Race is compartible with the RC832?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82285/discussion-between-alwin07-and-mike-petrichenko).